Power query changes the case after remove duplicate and load to powerbi
I load a simple table into  power query (two rows Marrick & MARRICK)
data in excel
I then remove duplicates and confirm the table still have two rows (Marrick & MARRICK). This is expected behavior here is the transformations I'm doing.
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\ladeby.klaes\OneDrive - GEA\Desktop\Book3.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(Sheet1_Sheet)
in
    #"Removed Duplicates"


When I Load the data into power bi, the table now reads Marrick & Marrick.
table in power bi.
How come power bi changes the case to the first cell value. The issues is, that the table no longer contains unique values. Any suggestions? I have seen this issue twice today for much bigger tables loaded with data flow, so my 1 to many relations suddenly needs to be changed to many-to-may.
It is not a solution to uppercase or lowercase before remove duplicates.
I first saw the issue loading a table with 60 K lines that should be the dimension table of my data model. Of reasons we build the dimension table from the raw data with Group By. This leads to same issue. When converted to ascii code i saw to different ascii codes for the duplicated values - which lead me to further investigate. It seemed like power bi changes the case when loading the data. I confirmed this in the most simple example (load a table with two cells).

This is a "feature" of Power BI. Has nothing to do with Excel and can be reproduced solely within Power BI. (Power Query in Power BI IS case-sensitive, however). See Chris Webb's blog Power BI And Case Sensitivity for more discussion.

Thx microsoft. I voted for case sensitivity here: https://ideas.fabric.microsoft.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=16b44cec-6a5b-ed11-a76e-281878a5e183
